# Possible to connect remotely only once. Repeated access required for second or more connection

Tags: networking, ssh, security, remote-access, ping

My office laptop has Ubuntu 18.04 OS. I used to seamlessly connect via RDP(xRDP) and VSCode from my Windows laptop. Few weeks backs I was on short vacation and when I assumed my work I am not able connect more than once to laptop.

- I can connect to office laptop via RDP and then I cannot via VSCode(which is SSH connection)
- My office laptop both via WiFi and LAN. So I used to connect RDP via WiFi IP address and VSCode via LAN IP address. But cannot connect to another VSCode session if I've to open another codebase remotely.
- Now I'm able access via one connection only! Either WiFi or LAN.

Within my office laptop, when connect on RDP or SSH, pings to self and other devices are perfectly fine. But other devices cannot access office until repeated trials resulting one successful ping. So not understanding why successive pings and remote accesses are failing?

`Sophos` is installed and asked IT guys if they ramped up security for remote devices? They said there was no such measures recently and asked to check my router for such issues. I did not find any issue with my router.

I tried `sudo ufw enable` & `sudo ufw allow from <ip_address>`. Rules are set properly. But still I'm facing the same issue.

How do I diagnose this issue to say is it laptop hardware issue or security software restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days after posting this I remembered that my laptop WiFi receiver had some issues while connecting, few years earlier. Plugged an USB WiFi adapter and tested if such issue persists. There is no such issues mentioned above while connecting via USB adapter.

Therefore the problem is with my built-in WiFi adapter on my personal laptop. No issue with office laptop or router.